# Sticky footer, but with multiple wrappers of same class

Tags: html, css

I have inherited a site with a div layout that I am not used to:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">...</div>
        <nav>...</nav>
        <div class="wrap">...<!-- main stuff -->...</div>
        <footer>
            <div class="wrap">...</div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

One of the pages has a small amount of content and so needs a sticky footer. Normally I would have used something like http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/ and set 100% etc etc in the CSS.

I don't really want to rewrite the structure of the site. Is there an alternative way to get the footer to the bottom of the screen while keeping this 'class of wrappers' structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap all your content first and leave the footer out of the wrap

```
<html>
<body>
   <div class="wrap-all">
    <div class="wrap">...</div>
    <nav>...</nav>
    <div class="wrap">...<!-- main stuff -->...</div>
    <footer>
        <div class="wrap">...</div>
    </footer>    
  </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Then the styles:

```
 html, body {
 height: 100%;
 }
.wrap-all {
 min-height: 100%;
 /* equal to footer height */
 margin-bottom: -142px; 
 }
 .wrap-all:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  }
 footer {
 /* .push must be the same height as footer */
 height: 142px; 
 }
```

Comment: This works great for the pages without scroll bars, but if a page exceeds the screen height and has a scroll bar then the footer is cut off by the bottom of the content.

Comment: Added height to the wrap-all css and this works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same CSS from the link you attached, just replace #footer with footer, because you already have  element in your structure.
If there's more  elements use something like body>footer.

So something like this (taken from the link you attached with just one modification):

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ee5;
}
```

And if you want to modify just footer .wrap div use footer>.wrap

Comment: This definitely moves the footer down, however, if I resize the browser to simulate a smaller screen then the footer cuts through the middle of my content. Additionally, my pages that scroll down have the footer in the middle of the content - is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: This answer is also correct when you use the example in the commented link, so up-voted. Thank you Slobodan. Marked Mario's as the answer as it provides an example which will continue to assist others without reliance on a link.